# why setLayoutDirection doesn't work in my Qt Quick demo?

Tags: qt, qml

I want to set my demo layout is Right to Left, and I set this in main function, like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    app.setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft)
    return app.exec();
}
```

Here is my qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    id:root
    Row {
        spacing: 20
        Repeater {
            model: 5
            Rectangle {
                color: "red"
                opacity: (5 - index) / 5
                width: 70; height: 30

                Text {
                    text: index + 1+" hello"
                    width:parent.width
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However the layout result still is left to right:
[image]

How can I get the real RTL layout, all components are right to left, include the text, just like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Right-to-left User Interfaces](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-righttoleft.html) says that you should use the [`LayoutMirroring`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layoutmirroring.html) attached properties. Taking the example from that page:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    LayoutMirroring.enabled: true
    LayoutMirroring.childrenInherit: true

    width: 300; height: 50
    color: "yellow"
    border.width: 1

    Row {
        anchors { left: parent.left; margins: 5 }
        y: 5; spacing: 5

        Repeater {
            model: 5

            Rectangle {
                color: "red"
                opacity: (5 - index) / 5
                width: 40; height: 40

                Text {
                    text: index + 1
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can put it pretty much anywhere, I think. In your case, just put those two lines below `id:root`.

Comment: Get it! Thanks, my friend. btw why LayoutMirroring doesn't work in Slider?

Comment: No worries. :) Controls 1 or Controls 2? It should work in Controls 2, but I'm not sure what the state is with Controls 1.